# Incomplete retrieving just after loading documents in CouchDB

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, couchdb

I access CouchDB (3.3.2 on Windows) from a Node application (written in typescript) through the application API.

It works perfectly when I load the db in batch and then, after some time, I search and retrieve the documents.

But for testing I create two documents in db through the application API, then try to retrieve them. Sometimes they are returned, sometimes only the first or second one are retrieved.

I tried to put a delay between creation and retrieval, but seems it does not help (or maybe I have waited too little). Or maybe the indices are not updated yet for the search and retrieval, or I don't know.

Is there any way to wait till or to known when the creation finished? It is needed only for testing.

Thanks in advance!
mario

Comment: Are you creating the document via PUT /db/doc? Are you awaiting the response, and which one are you getting - a "201 created" or a "202 accepted"? See https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/api/document/common.html#put--db-docid for the difference. The `/db/_bulk_docs` - endpoint only returns after the documents have been written to the disk.

Comment: I access db through `nano` js library and `await` all calls. I have to look how the return status is checked inside the library. Maybe I forgot to check for an error. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but when I removed `stale: "ok"` from the view call that was returning incomplete list of documents, then the error appears much less frequently. But I continue to investigate. Thanks!